# How to extend browser script timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JQuery that takes a while to run and after a few second I get the error:

Stop running this script?
A script on this page is causing internet explorer to run slowley. If it continues to run, your computer may become unresponsive

Is there a way to extend the timeout? I guess that would mean extending the timeout on the persons machine who browses to the URL

Answer (score 6):

If you're running your script under Google Chrome, you can disable the hang monitor with the flag: --disable-hang-monitor at the command line.

Under Mozilla based browsers (e.g., Firefox, Camino, SeaMonkey, Iceweasel), go to about:config and change the value of dom.max_script_run_time key.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking about programmatically changing it, you can't since it is an unsecured action and no browser will allow you to do it.

PS. As suggested above, try to understand the problem and refactor your code to reduce the execution time.

Answer (score 3):

Under Internet Explorer the maximum instruction allowed to run in a script before seeing timeout dialog is controlled by a registry key :

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Styles\MaxScriptStatements

This is a maximum statements so it shouldn't be related to how fast the computer run. There might be others values that I'm not aware of.

The default value is 5 000 000. Are you doing too much ?

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has its own timeout property. See: http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg15274.html

However the message you're getting is not a jQuery issue but a server or architecture issue.

Try to see if you're loading too many Ajax calls at the same time. See if you can change it to handle less calls at a time.

Also, check the server to see how long it takes to get a response. In long running XHR requests the server may take too long to respond.  In this case the server-side application or service needs modification.

Hope that helps.