# Loop stops after few iterations?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load a seuence of images (more than 1000 images) from a specific folder and show them one by one through changing the src of an existing image

```
var tid=0;

$("#hdn").load(function() {
    $("#myImg").attr('src',$("#hdn").attr('src'));
    tid = setTimeout(f,300);
    return false;
    });



    var locations = getActualFiles(); // this return an array containing urls of all images in the folder


    var i=0;
    f= function() { 

            $("#hdn").attr('src',locations[i]);
            i++;
            return false;

    };

    f();
```

This code works fine. The images keeps changing however it stops after 23 iterations. after loading the page few times and trying to change the code, now it stop on 44.png

I tried to load the image being on browser and it exists. So I tried to add this sinppet to my code in order to continue the sequence when an error is triggered :

```
$("#hdn").error(function() {
    $("#myImg").attr('src',$("#hdn").attr('src'));
    tid = setTimeout(f,300);
    return false;
    });
```

But the sequence still stop on image 44 and doesn't seem to continue.

Below is my html markup :

```
  <body style="padding:0;margin:0" bgcolor="#333">
  <img id="hdn" style="display:none" />
  <img id="myImg" />

  </body>
```

Here is the function that gets me the array of urls in desired folder :

```
  var getActualFiles = function () {
    "use strict";
    var rs = [];
    var nocache = new Date().getTime();
    $.ajax({
        url: '../streaming/returnArray.php?nocache='+nocache,
        data: {'sessid' : "<?=$sessid?>" },
        method: "GET",
        cache:false,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            rs = response;
        }
    });
    return rs;
};
```

I'm using async false because if I don't use it, it returns an empty array. Maybe because the folder has lots of images ?!

Comment: Well is `onerror` being triggered? `...load(...).on("error", function () { console.log("What about that", arguments); });`

Comment: Side note: You should probably do `var len = locations.length;` instead of calling `getActualFiles()` twice.

Comment: Probably an error occurs. Use the console log of your browser or a tool like FireBug to find out what it is.

Comment: Javascript running time is limited by Browser configuration. Since you have a huge amount of images you should try to handle it asynchronously. @see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948906/how-to-extend-browser-script-timeout

Comment: @abimelex What is not asynchronous about that code? lol

Comment: If you start the index at 40 instead of 0, does the same problem happen?

Comment: @epascarello it doesn't always stop at 40. It just stops at any number. 23, then 40, now it on 88... Is that a problem of memory ?!!!

Comment: I created a fiddle, and it looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/cudvyxo4/

Comment: I changed your jsfiddle with my images and didnt http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/cudvyxo4/

Comment: @PhilippWerminghausen It says in firebug Failed to load given url when I put cursor on the src attribute, but I can load the same url in browser ?

Comment: I can't see your images in the link. But that error just means you have to handle error, like everyone has been saying. Look at this, one of the links is gibberish but it does not break the loop: http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/cudvyxo4/5/

Answer (score 1):

Probably the image is not loading due to an error. Corrupt, not there, etc. So detect the error and than do something about it or ignore it.

```
$("#hdn").load(function() {
    $("#myImg").attr('src',$("#hdn").attr('src'));
    tid = setTimeout(f,300);
    return false;
}).on("error", function () {
    console.log("Could not load image", arguments);
    f(); //load next image        
});
```